# Prevent access from outside, mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Got a server exposed to the recent MongoDB ransom scam. https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/mongodb-databases-held-for-ransom-by-mysterious-attacker/

I closed it down until I fixed this.

What's the easiest way to fix this? Is to add a user?

```
mongo
use admin
db.createUser( { user: "root", pwd: "password", roles: [ "root" ] } )
```

Is this enough to avoid getting hacked?

Comment: One thing is auth of course, but another is server side specifics such a tunneling your data through private networks owned by you. In cloud based service like AWS and Racskpace it is easy to make your own virtual private network. On other services you may need to negotiate to get it working

Comment: I know but I don't have time at this point to tunneling etc. Right now I just need an easy temp fix.

Comment: Well, according to the link it is specifically "open" MongoDBs so yes, auth will fix it for the time being but seriously, tunneling should have been done when the DB was setup, it is recommended in the MongoDB docs

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Sammye's comment mongodb has often no password for a database user. This is especially problematic if the database is facing the public internet because, just by trying the right port on the ip adress of your server everyone in the internet could theoretically connect to the database server.

To prevent this it is always a good idea to limit the traffic that can reach your server and its ports by a firewall.

Here is a sample iptables configuration (for ubuntu):

the following commands allow all traffic to localhost and to the ports 22 (ssh), 80 (http) and 443 (https)

```
# accept local traffic
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# allow established connections
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# allow connections to ports 22, 80, 443
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

these commands block the rest of the traffic:

```
# drops the rest of the traffic to the server
# sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
# disables the possibility to route traffic through the server (you may or may not want to use this) 
# sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP
# makes it possible to send data from the server
# sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Before running any of these iptables commands it is always a good idea to set up a cronjob that resets your iptables configuration every 5 minutes. In that case if something goes wrong (you lock yourself out of the server for example because you forgot to enable port 22 in your firewall) the rules get reset and you can fix the issue. 
this is a script from the iptables ubunt wiki to reset the firewall:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

```
echo "Stopping firewall and allowing everyone..."
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

**when everything is finished and seems to be working do not forget to install the package iptables-persistent** (by default the iptables rules only exist until the server is restarted)

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

this is by far not a complete guide on how to secure your server with iptables as firewall but I hope that it can get you started.

Now the database is only reachable from the server on not from the public internet anymore. To access your database from the public internet anyways you will have to create a ssh tunnel to your server:

```
ssh youruser@yourdomain_or_ip_adress -f -N -L 27019:yourdomain_or_ip_adress:27019
```

-f -N -L **27019** <-- here you define the port that should be used on **your** **machine** for the database traffic

yourdomain_or_ip_adress:**27019** <-- this is the **port** that the database runs on **on** your **server**

When this is done you should  be able to access the database from your server at your local machine at 127.0.0.1:27019.

This is a more general way to secure any application that runs on a server that is exposed to the internet. 
There is also an official guide on how to specifically secure mongodb internally you can find it here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/

Comment: is this manual config of iptables needed if you are running `ufw` ? setting rules there seems much easier... however I'm having trouble getting it to work